# Add to Home Screen mini-infobar not triggering for my app

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to trigger chrome mini-infobar for my PWA

[image]

I have checked that the page meets the add to home screen criteria, it also successfully passes 
PWA audit in chrome devtools:

[image]

- The web app is not already installed (not installed)
- Meets a user engagement heuristic (currently, the user has interacted with the domain for at least 30 seconds) (nothing happens after 30s)
- Includes a web app manifest that includes:
  short_name or name icons must include a 192px and a 512px sized icons
  start_url display must be one of fullscreen, standalone, or minimal-ui (yes)
- Served over HTTPS (required for service workers) (yes)
- Has registered a service worker with a fetch event handler (yes)

The most strange thing is that mini-infobar IS shown to the user when testing from local machine (using remote devices port forwarding). But it stops working after I upload it to the web.

My manifest:

```
{
"name": "Dota 2 counterpick",
"short_name": "Counterpick",
"start_url": "/?utm_source=homescreen",
"icons": [{
    "src": "/android-chrome-192x192.png",
    "sizes": "192x192",
    "type": "image/png"
}, {
    "src": "/android-chrome-512x512.png",
    "sizes": "512x512",
    "type": "image/png"
}],
"theme_color": "#ffffff",
"background_color": "#ffffff",
"display": "standalone"
}
```

Service worker

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

I tried unregistering service worker, resetting site data, relaunching chrome but no luck. I'm using Chrome 71 on Android 8.1

PWA url: https://counterpick.herokuapp.com

Comment: Oh wait! Where you append resources to Cache storage?

Comment: I'm not saving anything into it right now. Service worker will make network request if item was not found in cache (`|| fetch` part) so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Curiously, the prompt does appear on my device. Try resetting the cache?

Comment: Wow, prompt does appear in Chrome Beta (which is using separate, user profile). Thank you very much for checking.
I thought it was a problem with my app, but it seems to be some internal chrome caching (i have never dismissed this prompt so there must be some other heuristics). Resetting cache/site data/serviceworker did not help.

Comment: Works instantly in Chrome 71 android. Are you sure you Uninstalled any previous tests (icon is now located with your app icons) and fully cleared your browser's cache?

Comment: 100% sure, my assumption that it's probably stored somewhere in the profile folder but cannot be cleared by the user.

Comment: Just in case you have not looked there, on my machine it gets installed in (Users>MyUserName>Applications>Chrome Apps) folder (which may not help if this is on another's machine you cannot see). Hope you figure it out.